# Best way to show truncated data in ObjectListView cell

Tags: python, wxpython, tooltip, objectlistview

One of the columns in my ObjectListView contains data that is too long to display completely, so it's automatically truncated. I would like a way to display all the data in the cell. I've already implemented the suggestion in [this tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/12/12/wxpython-adding-tooltips-objectlistview/), but I'm not very happy with the result because the tooltip is for the entire list, not just that list item. Ideally, I'd like to have exactly what's pictured in the first image of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415104/how-to-tweak-my-tooltips-in-wxpython).

That post mentions that the expansion-on-hover behavior happens automatically, but I don't see any way of recreating that behavior. Perhaps it only happens on Windows? I'm running on GTK.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the column width to be wider?

Comment: Actually the tooltip will change depending on which item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could always implement an on right click pop-up window that you can populate with whatever you would like - see the wxPython Demo for Pop-up windows as a starting point.

Alternatively you could switch from ObjectListView to wx.lib.agw.UltimateListCtrl or DataViewControl - both of these seem to support tooltips that are aware of which row and column you are hovering over.

Comment: This is not a bad alternative, but I would rather have something that doesn't require a click.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with the code in my [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/12/12/wxpython-adding-tooltips-objectlistview/) using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415104/how-to-tweak-my-tooltips-in-wxpython) you had mentioned and came up with the following:

```
import wx
from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn

########################################################################
class Book(object):
    """
    Model of the Book object

    Contains the following attributes:
    'ISBN', 'Author', 'Manufacturer', 'Title'
    """
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, title, author, isbn, mfg):
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.author = author
        self.mfg = mfg
        self.title = title


########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.products = [Book("wxPython in Action", "Robin Dunn",
                              "1932394621", "Manning"),
                         Book("Hello World", "Warren and Carter Sande",
                              "1933988495", "Manning")
                         ]

        self.dataOlv = ObjectListView(self, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                      style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.dataOlv.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.updateTooltip)
        self.setBooks()

        # Allow the cell values to be edited when double-clicked
        self.dataOlv.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_SINGLECLICK

        # create an update button
        updateBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Update OLV")
        updateBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.updateControl)

        # Create some sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)        

        mainSizer.Add(self.dataOlv, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(updateBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateControl(self, event):
        """
        Update the control
        """
        print "updating..."
        #product_dict = [{"title":"Core Python Programming", "author":"Wesley Chun",
                         #"isbn":"0132269937", "mfg":"Prentice Hall"},
                        #{"title":"Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner",
                         #"author":"Michael Dawson", "isbn":"1598631128",
                         #"mfg":"Course Technology"},
                        #{"title":"Learning Python", "author":"Mark Lutz",
                         #"isbn":"0596513984", "mfg":"O'Reilly"}
                        #]

        product_list = [Book("Core Python Programming", "Wesley Chun",
                             "0132269937", "Prentice Hall"),
                        Book("Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner",
                             "Michael Dawson", "1598631128", "Course Technology"),
                        Book("Learning Python", "Mark Lutz", "0596513984",
                             "O'Reilly")
                        ]

        data = self.products + product_list
        self.dataOlv.SetObjects(data)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setBooks(self, data=None):
        """
        Sets the book data for the OLV object
        """
        self.dataOlv.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("Title", "left", 220, "title"),
            ColumnDefn("Author", "left", 200, "author"),
            ColumnDefn("ISBN", "right", 100, "isbn"),
            ColumnDefn("Mfg", "left", 180, "mfg")
        ])

        self.dataOlv.SetObjects(self.products)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateTooltip(self, event):
        """
        """
        pos = wx.GetMousePosition()
        mouse_pos = self.dataOlv.ScreenToClient(pos)
        item_index, flag = self.dataOlv.HitTest(mouse_pos)
        print flag
        if flag == wx.LIST_HITTEST_ONITEMLABEL:
            msg = "%s is a good book!" % self.dataOlv.GetItemText(item_index)
            self.dataOlv.SetToolTipString(msg)
        else:
            self.dataOlv.SetToolTipString("")

        event.Skip()

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, 
                          title="ObjectListView Demo", size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """
    Run the demo
    """
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also updated my tutorial to include the code above. Please note that the tooltip only updates when you mouse through the cells in the first column. I haven't found a good way around that.