# wxPython - Add tooltip to menu items

Tags: python, wxpython, tooltip

How do I add tooltips to elements of a wx.Menu()? Here's the code I've written for the items:

```
#Patient menu (1st menu):
self.patientMenu = wx.Menu()
self.registerNewPatient = self.patientMenu.Append( -1, 'Cadastrar paciente...' )
self.listPatientsByName = self.patientMenu.Append( -1, u'Listar pacientes em ordem alfabética' )
self.listPatientsByNumber = self.patientMenu.Append( -1, u'Listar pacientes por número em ordem crescente' )
self.searchForPatients = self.patientMenu.Append( -1, 'Pesquisar paciente(s)...' )
#Appointment menu (2nd menu):
self.appointmentMenu = wx.Menu()
self.seeAppointmentsForToday = self.appointmentMenu.Append( -1, 'Visualizar consultas de hoje' )
self.registerNewAppointment = self.appointmentMenu.Append( -1, 'Marcar consulta...' )
self.cancelAppointment = self.appointmentMenu.Append( -1, 'Desmarcar consulta...' )
self.seeAppointmentsForOtherSpecificDate = self.appointmentMenu.Append( -1, 'Pesquisar consultas...' )
#Exit menu (3rd menu):
self.exitMenu = wx.Menu()
self.exitProgram = self.exitMenu.Append( -1, 'Encerrar' )
#Menu bar:
self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
self.menuBar.Append( self.patientMenu, 'Paciente' )
self.menuBar.Append( self.appointmentMenu, 'Consulta' )
self.menuBar.Append( self.exitMenu, 'Sair' )
self.SetMenuBar( self.menuBar )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could gather it looks like the consensus is that you would want to bind an event to listen to `wx.EVT_MENU_HIGHLIGHT` or `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED` then grab the `id` of the selected menu perhaps with [`GetMenuId`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MenuEvent.html#MenuEvent.GetMenuId) and  using some sort of map/dict display the help message, or it looks like it might be possible to [Set the help string](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Menu.html?highlight=menu#Menu.SetHelpString) Although it looks like this could be another possible solution:

- [How to tweak my tooltips in wxpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415104/how-to-tweak-my-tooltips-in-wxpython?rq=1)

Also see `balloontip`:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.balloontip.html

I am not sure if this is still the case, as some of these answers are a bit dated.

Related:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/nf3bcDGdyTM
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/-eH2UdtqV9g
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/12/12/wxpython-adding-tooltips-objectlistview/

Comment: Thank you for the links. Actually, I didn't think like this. I was hoping there as an easy way to do that, in order to provide the menu elements with simple tooltips.

Comment: There is: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ToolTip.html?highlight=tooltip ... but this seems to be for the entire window. You may get a response from Mike or Robin if they get the time. They are generally pretty active on the wxpython tag. Also I added another link to balloontip.